# How to get row count when a particular field is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, null

```
RowID       TimeReceived    TimeRead    tbl_user_UserID     tbl_message_MsgID

  5     2011-09-06 11:16:20   NULL               2                1
  6     2011-09-06 11:17:04   NULL               3                1
  7     2011-09-06 11:17:19   NULL               100              1
```

This is my table

```
 command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Distinct RowID) FROM tbl_usermessage WHERE TimeRead= NULL AND tbl_message_MsgID=@Value1", connectionString);
         command.Parameters.Add("@value1", MySqlDbType.Int32, 25);
         command.Parameters["@value1"].Value = MessageID;
         int nnnID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

I want to count the row where time read is null, it gives me 0 as output where it should be 3. Where am I going wrong. i have set the default value for time read as null.

Comment: would work only if `ANSI_NULLS` is off

Comment: Why are you using `COUNT(Distinct RowID) ` rather than `COUNT(*)`? Not clear that this is needed from the rest of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is incorrect. You can check for NULL by using `IS NULL`:

```
 command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Distinct RowID) FROM tbl_usermessage WHERE TimeRead IS NULL AND tbl_message_MsgID=@Value1", connectionString);
         command.Parameters.Add("@value1", MySqlDbType.Int32, 25);
         command.Parameters["@value1"].Value = MessageID;
         int nnnID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 3):

Query for getting count

```
select count(Distinct RowID) from table where TimeRead is null
```

Comment: Agreed, TimeRead=null is always false.  Nothing is equal to null.

Comment: This query will always return `0`

Answer (score 2):

Use "`is NULL`" instead of "`= NULL`"

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct RowID) FROM tbl_usermessage WHERE TimeRead is NULL ...
```

Also check if your parameter `@value1` is correct!